# How to set permissions?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I need to set users permissions, i tried

```
chanel2.overwritePermissions(message.member,{'SEND_MESSAGES': true,'READ_MESSAGES': true})
```

but it overwrited all permissions (for everyone not just message.member), not just add specific permissions for message.member (but for the 1 member, it does what i need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its best if you refer to [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#adding-overwrites) for all of the information you need to know about setting user permissions in a channel. It looks like it is erroring because `message.member` is not grabbing the user id to set in the overwritePermissions. Ill explain it all here, but next time try adding some error information and context to your question and code :)

You need to make sure that you have a channel object, so you can grab that like so:

```
const channelID = message.channel.id //alternatively you can hardcode one like so: "588868740980932620"
const channel = message.guild.channels.find(c => {return c.id === channelID})
```

After you grab the channel object, you can now set the channel permissions like so:

```
// channel is whatever your constant variable is in the section above
// message.member.user.id is identical to message.author.id
channel.overwritePermissions(message.member.user.id, {
 SEND_MESSAGES: true,
 READ_MESSAGES: true,
 ATTACH_FILES: true
});
```

You can find permission flags [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.5.1/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS).

Hopefully, this helps you. [DiscordJS Guide](https://discordjs.guide) and [Discord JS Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs) are very helpful areas to look for help.

Comment: but my problem is, that when i dont put there the line, it is ok, but when i put it there, the permissions will reset

Comment: Maybe edit your question and provide what you are trying to achieve and what happens when you try something different

Comment: I solved it by merging both permission arrays and applying them as one.